# switch boolean to false or true with the same button

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a `boolean` switch between true and false when i press the same Mouse button.

This is the code i have written:

```
if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
            Mouse.setGrabbed(true);
        } else if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
            Mouse.setGrabbed(false);
        }
       if(Mouse.isGrabbed()){
           camera.processMouse(1, 80, -80);
       }
```

this doesn't work, it doesn't react the second time i press the mouse button.

Comment: Why are your `if` and `else if` conditions identical?  How will control ever reach the `else if` clause?

Comment: it is my desperat attempt to make it go false the second time i push the Mouse button. sorry i dont claim to be an expert on this stuff that is why i consult with you guys :)

Comment: @user3677855-Kindly check the answer which I have posted below.If any mistake,kindly inform me.

Comment: It's important to THINK about what you're coding.  Simply copying some code and tweaking a few things is not the way to do it.  Start from scratch and THINK through each step.  (StackOverflow is not a "Write my code for me" site.)

Comment: i dont see it as such Hot Licks! but i think it is important to make sure the code works before studying it..... i got 4 replies already and none of them work as i intend to yet therefore i find it incredibly stupid to study their code hard. I guarentee you that when the solution is found then i will study it very closely so that i wont have to ask you guys this question again. Im sorry if my learning methods offend you though i cant see anything wrong with them.

Comment: So why do you expect that code you got "for free" from some point-seeker with a 200 rep will be any good?  I didn't say find some code and study it, I said think about what you need to do and then write the appropriate code.  Code examples are sometimes good to help you understand a difficult concept, but at the end of the day you have to write your own, not copy someone else's.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
        Mouse.setGrabbed( !Mouse.isGrabbed() );
    } 
   if(Mouse.isGrabbed()){
       camera.processMouse(1, 80, -80);
   }
```

The '!' sign reverses the given true/false value so !true gives false and !false gives true.

Comment: We are getting VERY close! but it only reacts some of the times when i push the button. so i end up pushing randomly 1-10 times before it reacts to my pushing.

Comment: Does your program reach the code everytime you push the button? You can test this by setting a breakpoint or printing something like 'button pushed'

Comment: alright something is up here. i have tried adding a System.out.println to it and the couple of times i tried pushing the mouse it printed it 4 - 7 times per push.

Comment: Mouse is imported. 

import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;

i dont know if this helps. i must confess myself lost atm.

Comment: Well, I've never used LWJGL myself so I'm afraid I can't help you with that. However, it does give the answer to why your button is wonky. You flip the 'grabbed' value a random amount of times, so you get random results.

Comment: Yeah you are right. i will make another question now. regarding this problem with the LWJGL mouse. Thank so much Simon! and all you other guys who took ya time to figure this problem out

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your game!

Comment: btw Simon i found a solution!

while(Mouse.next()) {
       if (Mouse.getEventButton() == 1) {
        if (Mouse.getEventButtonState()) {
         Mouse.setGrabbed(true); 
        }
        else 
         Mouse.setGrabbed(false);
       }
        if(Mouse.isGrabbed()){
              camera.processMouse(1, 80, -80);
             }
      }

Comment: Nice job! Good luck with the rest.

Answer (score -2):

With little modification

```
   if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
        Mouse.setGrabbed(true);
    } else{
        Mouse.setGrabbed(false);
    }
   if(Mouse.isGrabbed()){
       camera.processMouse(1, 80, -80);
   }
```

Comment: I have tried this. it doesn't react at all when i push the button. when i use this code it is as if setGrabbed is false constantly which is okay but it doesn't go true when i push the button or hold it down.

Comment: Your answer doesn't serve his purpose!